# PHP Multi-form Trouble

Tags: php, html, forms

Hello Fellow Stackers,

New to PHP and I am putting together a multipage form from pre-built code.

Basically the user selects as many checkboxes as they want... then the form submits to this secondary page. This secondary page echo's the checkboxes they chose at the top of the page via `$check`.. then they can enter their contact information and all of the information gets submitted via form, along with the `$check` information.

Everything is working perfectly except `$check` isn't being entered into the form message, but it works up at the top of the page, displaying which options the user inputted.

Any help is appreciated!

```
<?php
$emailOut = '';
if(!empty($_POST['choices'])) {
foreach($_POST['choices'] as $check) {
            echo $check; //echoes the value set in the HTML form for each checked checkbox.
                     //so, if I were to check 1, 3, and 5 it would echo value 1, value 3, value 5.
                     //in your case, it would echo whatever $row['Report ID'] is equivalent to.
            $emailOut .= $check."\n"; //any output you want
}
}
$errors = '';
$myemail = 'test@myemailHERE.com';//<-----Put Your email address here.
if(empty($_POST['name'])  || 
   empty($_POST['email']) || 
   empty($_POST['message']))
{
$errors .= "\n Error: all fields are required";
}

$name = $_POST['name']; 
$email_address = $_POST['email']; 
$message = $_POST['message']; 

if (!preg_match(
"/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i", 
$email_address))
{
    $errors .= "\n Error: Invalid email address";
}

if( empty($errors))
{
$to = $myemail; 
$email_subject = "Contact form submission: $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message. $check ".
" Here are the details:\n Name: $name \n Email: $email_address \n Message \n $message \n $emailOut"; 

$headers = "From: $myemail\n"; 
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";

mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
//redirect to the 'thank you' page
header('Location: contact-form-thank-you.html');
} 
?>
```

Comment: Can you show the code you're using for the checkboxes?

Comment: basically all like this: <input id="2nd choice" value="2nd choice" name="choices[]" type="checkbox" />  

They are all carrying over into the echo properly at the top of the page... just not showing up on the email output.

Comment: You're not actually iterating through the checks down in the message, only at the top. You'll need to use that foreach at the top to put the choices into a string, which you can then use in the $email_body. Or re-use the foreach below.

Comment: can I implode the array into a string then ? Would that be the best way to do this?  

$string = implode(" ", $array);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing in this situation is that when you get down to the email, `$check` is the last option displayed. You need to use the `foreach` statment to build the array or email output such as

```
$emailOut = "";
foreach($_POST['choices'] as $check) {
        $emailOut .= $check."\n"; //any output you want
}
```

Then use your email variable in the same way

```
$email_body = "You have received a new message. Here are the details:\n Name: $name \n Email: $email_address \n Message \n     $message \n $emailOut";
```

**UPDATE**

From further investigation and more code submitted, it appears that you are working with a multi-form submssion issue. The issue is you have form 1 (checkboxes) that submits to form 2 (email).

Since when doing the checks after the checkbox submission, no name, email, etc was given so `$errors` were given and no email sent. When filling out the email form, the checkboxes were not sent again so `$check` or even `$_POST['choices']` had values.

You can either put the two forms into one, or you can look into a way to save the values by passing them and filling a 'hidden' field (`<input type='hidden' value='...'>)` or use a session with PHP.

Comment: Thanks! I am trying this but fear my syntax may be off. I changed the var to $emailOut in my email body... then change the top lines to this: 

<?php
$emailOut = '';
if(!empty($_POST['choices'])) {
    foreach($_POST['choices'] as $check) {
             echo $check; 
                    $emailOut .= $check."\n"; 
    }
}

Comment: are you still having troubles? cause it wont effect the output if you put the `echo $check;` in the foreach other than raise an error when it gets to your `header(Location: ...)`

Comment: Yes lol.

I left the echo in the foreach and it is working properly. It is echoing the checkbox choice from the page before, but the form is still leaving the variable out when it gets emailed. I am getting no errors in dreamweaver, and no errors on the webserver that I can see.

Comment: do you get any errors? Can you post an example submission and an example email you are getting? Your code is working fine for me. Also, post your html form

Comment: http://curv.net/formbeta/

Sample email looks like this:

You have received a new message.   Here are the details:
 **Name**: asdsa 
 **Email**: simon@frank.com 
 **Message**
 SAD

Comment: big thanks UnholyRanger. I'll probably go with hidden input types.